# Escribir mail (Mailto) desde el cliente en el servidor. Eval no funciona

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Estoy intentando colocar un botón en el `Grid`. Todo correcto si pongo un mail por defecto. La cuestión es que quiero colocarle a cada una de las filas el que le corresponde (ya existe también una columna con ese mail).

En este caso si funciona:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ContactosGridView" 
        DataSourceID="sqlContactos" 
        ClientInstanceName="ContactosGridView" 
        EnableRowsCache="False" 
        runat="server" 
        KeyFieldName="IdContacto"
        OnHtmlDataCellPrepared="GridView_HtmlDataCellPrepared">
    <ClientSideEvents RowClick="function(s, e) {  SMCVisitasClientesDetalleVisita_OpenDialogSeeContact(e); }"
        CustomButtonClick="function(s, e) {
                                if(e.buttonID == 'SendEmail'){
                                    window.location.href('mailto:person@mail.es');
                                }
                            }" />
    <Settings ShowGroupPanel="true" ShowFilterRow="true" />
    <SettingsPager PageSize="20"></SettingsPager>
    <SettingsBehavior ConfirmDelete="true" />
    <Styles>
        <AlternatingRow Enabled="true" />
    </Styles>
    <Columns>
    </Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Pero en el momento que intento colocar un Eval, como tengo ya en otras aplicaciones web, me casca. Sea en el mailto, en un console log, alert...

```
window.location.href('mailto:<%#Eval("Email")%>');
```

Que puede estar pasando? Alguna idea de como solucionarlo? me estoy vovliendo loco y es lo que me queda para terminar el proyecto casi.

PD: las columnas del grid y el boton se imprimen enteras desde el lado del servidor.

Botón:

```
private void AddCommandColumn()
{
    GridViewCommandColumn commandColumn = new GridViewCommandColumn();
    commandColumn.Name = DevExpressInfraestructure.V11.Core.Definitions.Grid.CommandColumnName;
    commandColumn.ButtonType = ButtonType.Image;
    commandColumn.ClearFilterButton.Visible = true;
    commandColumn.ClearFilterButton.Image.Url = DevExpressInfraestructure.V11.Core.Definitions.Images.Cancel;
    commandColumn.ClearFilterButton.Image.ToolTip = DevExpressTexts.Keys.ClearFilter.GetLiteral();
    commandColumn.VisibleIndex = DevExpressInfraestructure.V11.Core.Definitions.Grid.CommandColumnIndex;
    commandColumn.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "SMCGridCommandColumn";
    this.ContactosGridView.Columns.Add(commandColumn);
    this.SendEmailButton(commandColumn, ButtonsId.SendEmail, Resources.Keys.SendEmail.Get());
}
```

---

```
private void SendEmailButton(GridViewCommandColumn column, string id, string text)
{
    GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton suscriberButton = new GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton();
    //suscriberButton.Image.Url = DevExpressInfraestructure.V11.Core.Definitions.Images.SendEmail;
    suscriberButton.Image.Url = "http://XXXX/Style%20Library/Images/send.png";
    suscriberButton.ID = id;
    suscriberButton.Text = text;
    column.CustomButtons.Add(suscriberButton);
}
```

---

```
private void LoadGrid()
{
    // Set grid view colums            
    this.ContactosGridView.AddGridViewDataColumn(new GridField(Contacto.Columns.NombreContacto, Resources.Keys.ContactoPrincipalFrm.Get().TrimEnd(':'), AutoFilterCondition.Contains));
    this.ContactosGridView.AddGridViewDataColumn(new GridField(Contacto.Columns.CodigoCliente, Resources.Keys.CodigoCliente.Get().TrimEnd(':'), AutoFilterCondition.Contains));
    this.ContactosGridView.AddGridViewDataColumn(new GridField(Contacto.Columns.NombreCliente, Resources.Keys.NombreCliente.Get().TrimEnd(':'), AutoFilterCondition.Contains));
    if (this.ExportExcelMode)
    {
        this.ContactosGridView.AddGridViewDataColumn(new GridField(Contacto.Columns.Direccion, Resources.Keys.Direccion.Get().TrimEnd(':'), AutoFilterCondition.Contains));
    }
    this.ContactosGridView.AddGridViewDataColumn(new GridField(Contacto.Columns.CodigoPostalPoblacion, Resources.Keys.CodigoPostalPoblacion.Get().TrimEnd(':'), AutoFilterCondition.Contains));
    this.ContactosGridView.AddGridViewDataColumn(new GridField(Contacto.Columns.Email, Resources.Keys.EMailFrm.Get().TrimEnd(':'), AutoFilterCondition.Contains));
    this.ContactosGridView.AddGridViewDataColumn(new GridField(Contacto.Columns.Movil, Resources.Keys.MovilFrm.Get().TrimEnd(':'), AutoFilterCondition.Contains));
    this.ContactosGridView.AddGridViewDataColumn(new GridField(Contacto.Columns.Telefono, Resources.Keys.TelefonoFrm.Get().TrimEnd(':'), AutoFilterCondition.Contains));
    this.ContactosGridView.AddGridViewDataColumn(new GridField(Contacto.Columns.Departamento, Resources.Keys.DepartamentoFrm.Get().TrimEnd(':'), AutoFilterCondition.Contains));
    this.ContactosGridView.AddGridViewDataColumn(new GridField(Contacto.Columns.Cargo, Resources.Keys.CargoFrm.Get().TrimEnd(':'), AutoFilterCondition.Contains));
    if (this.ExportExcelMode)
    {
        this.ContactosGridView.AddGridViewDataColumn(new GridField(Contacto.Columns.Descripcion, Resources.Keys.DescripcionFrm.Get().TrimEnd(':'), AutoFilterCondition.Contains));
    }
    this.ContactosGridView.AddGridViewDataColumn(new GridField(Contacto.Columns.Relevancia, Resources.Keys.Relevancia.Get().TrimEnd(':'), AutoFilterCondition.Contains));
    if (this.ExportExcelMode)
    {
        this.ContactosGridView.AddGridViewDataColumn(new GridField(Contacto.Columns.Observaciones, Resources.Keys.ObservacionesFrm.Get().TrimEnd(':'), AutoFilterCondition.Contains));
    }
    this.ContactosGridView.AddGridViewDataColumn(new GridField(Contacto.Columns.Acciones, Resources.Keys.AccionesMarketingFrm.Get().TrimEnd(':'), AutoFilterCondition.Contains));
    this.ContactosGridView.AddGridViewDataColumn(new GridField(Contacto.Columns.Holon, Resources.Keys.Holon.Get().TrimEnd(':'), AutoFilterCondition.Contains));
    this.ContactosGridView.AddGridViewDataColumn(new GridField(Contacto.Columns.Proyecto, Resources.Keys.proyecto.Get().TrimEnd(':'), AutoFilterCondition.Contains));
    if (this.ExportExcelMode)
    {
        this.ContactosGridView.AddGridViewDataColumn(new GridField(Contacto.Columns.Segmento, Resources.Keys.Segmento.Get().TrimEnd(':'), AutoFilterCondition.Contains));
        this.ContactosGridView.AddGridViewDataColumn(new GridField(Contacto.Columns.Subsegmento, Resources.Keys.SegmentoActividad.Get().TrimEnd(':'), AutoFilterCondition.Contains));
        this.ContactosGridView.AddGridViewDataColumn(new GridField(Contacto.Columns.Responsable, Resources.Keys.AtResponsable.Get().TrimEnd(':'), AutoFilterCondition.Contains));
    }

    this.AddCommandColumn();
    this.ContactosGridView.SetGrid(false, false, false);

}
```

Y ya el load grid lo llamo en el page load

Comment: Revisa estos enlaces [1](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q402544/aspxgridview-how-to-add-an-e-mail-column-link) y [2](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q520222/aspxgridview-how-to-change-mail-to-hyperlink-mailto) en la documentación de DevExpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido poner algo mas apropiado para la situación. He colocado esto en una de las columnas. Ahora el problema que tengo es que actua como una mas de la fila, y cuando la clico, aparte del mail, me abre tambien el modal del perfil xD

```
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn VisibleIndex="99">
    <DataItemTemplate>
        <a href="mailto:<%#Eval("Email")%>"><img src="http://XXXX/Style%20Library/Images/send.png" /></a>
    </DataItemTemplate>
</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

Buenas, podrías probar con lo siguiente:

```
window.location.href = "mailto:"+<%#Eval("Email")%>;
```

EDIT: Como he dicho en el comentario, creo que el problema va a estar en las comillas, que rompen las sentencias. En este link tienen un problema similar y con el escapado de caracteres lo solucionan: [OnClick Eval() escapando caracteres](https://forums.asp.net/t/980311.aspx?Eval%20in%20an%20OnCLientClick).

Espero ser de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: tengo un boton que se imprime desde el ascx.cs (custombutton,...) y desde el ascx le añado el javascript que he colgado. Pero me casca... Estoy intentandolo con una funcion s,e para sacar a las otras columnas de la misma fila a ver :S

Comment: Se podría considerar que el botón tiene / pertenece a un Databound? Para que pueda ir recogiendo email digo.

Comment: Te he colgado el codigo que uso para imprimir el boton.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta y he puesto un link a ver si te sirve, ya que veo que tú código del botón desde mi punto de vista está perfecto :)

Comment: La cosa es que no funciona, porque cada linea es un mail diferente, y no debe poder imprimir el eval dinamicamente.

Answer (score 0):

Le he colocado esta ñapa bastante guarrilla, pero me funciona:

Al hacer click la clase del row cambia a focused. Por lo que busco esa clase, luego busco el 4 td dentro, y saco el html.

```
function AbrirMailToe(e) {
    var email = $('.dxgvFocusedRow').find('.dxgv').eq(4).html();
    window.location = 'mailto:' + email;
}
```

Comment: Es bastante "poco bonita", pero es efectivo, me lo voy a apuntar en lista de tareas y a ver si en unos días me creo un ejemplo similar y le echo un rato que ya me he quedado con la curiosidad. Saludos!!

Comment: "poco bonita"? jajaja es mas fea que un murcielago maquillado jajaja. Gracias por todo, a ver si conseguimos embellecer a este sapo :P